# position:absolute breaks CSS dropdown

Tags: css

I am making something with ace editor. As part of this, I have a dropdown menu that allows theme selection. This is on a bar at the top, (which will eventually have more options). I know that, in order to position the bar at the very top, I need to use `position:absolute` in the CSS code. However, this breaks the dropdown, and it no longer actually drops down. To see what I mean, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/PorygonZRocks/mdfqs4xq/) is a fiddle. (To compare, removing `position: absolute` in the CSS for `#navbar` makes it work fine, but is not at the very top [most visible in a full window].)
Note: In the fiddle, I have removed everything not related to the navbar, such as the ace code.

Comment: Please re-read the [tour]. Adding [Solved] to your title is bad, and incorporating an answer in your question post even worse practise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you remove the `max-height` from `.dropChoices`, the `bottom` and `overflow` on `#navbar`

```js
// The function changeTheme() is defined in the full code
function toggle(button) {
    var dropList = button.nextElementSibling;

    function isDropdown() {
        return (" " + dropList.className + " ").indexOf(" dropChoices ") > -1;
    }
    while (!isDropdown) {
        dropList = dropList.nextElementSibling;
    }
    dropList.classList.toggle("hidden");
    window.onclick = function(e) {
        if (!e.target.matches('.dropButton') && !e.target.matches('.dropChoices')) {
            if (!dropList.classList.contains('hidden')) {
                dropList.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: dimgray;
}
.navOption {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 13px;
}
.dropButton {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.navOption:hover, .navOption:active, .navOption:focus {
    background-color: gray;
    outline: none;
}
.dropChoices {
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 5;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
.dropChoices p {
    color: black;
    outline: none;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropChoices p:hover, .dropChoices p:focus {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
p.dropTitle {
    cursor: initial;
}
p.dropTitle:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- This code is slightly shortened, and only contains the relevant things -->
<div id="navbar">
   <button onclick="toggle(this)" class="dropButton navOption">Themes</button>
   <div id="themesList" class="dropChoices hidden">
    <p class="dropTitle"><b>Light</b></p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="chrome" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Chrome</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="clouds" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Clouds</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="crimson_editor" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Crimson Editor</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="dawn" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Dawn</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="dreamweaver" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Dreamweaver</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="eclipse" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Eclipse</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="gitHub" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">GitHub</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="iplastic" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">IPlastic</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="solarized_light" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Solarized Light</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="textmate" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">TextMate</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="tomorrow" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Tomorrow</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="xcode" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">XCode</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="kuroir" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Kuroir</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="katzenmilch" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">KatzenMilch</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="sqlserver" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">SQL Server</p>
    <p class="dropTitle"><b>Dark</b></p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="ambiance" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Ambiance</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="chaos" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Chaos</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="clouds_midnight" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Clouds Midnight</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="cobalt" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Cobalt</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="gruvbox" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Gruvbox</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="idle_fingers" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">idle Fingers</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="kr_theme" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">krTheme</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="merbivore" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Merbivore</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="merbivore_soft" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Merbivore Soft</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="mono_industrial" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Mono Industrial</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="monokai" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Monokai</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="pastel_on_dark" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Pastel on dark</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="solarized_dark" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Solarized Dark</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="terminal" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Terminal</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="tomorrow_night" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Tomorrow Night</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="tomorrow_night_blue" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Tomorrow Night Blue</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="tomorrow_night_bright" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Tomorrow Night Bright</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="tomorrow_night_eighties" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Tomorrow Night 80s</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="twilight" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Twilight</p>
                <p tabindex="0" id="vibrant_ink" onclick="changeTheme(this.id)">Vibrant Ink</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This does work, but I need max-height for the scrollbar to work.

Comment: does `#navbar` have to be `position: absolute`?

Comment: Actually, ignore my comment. I just had to change the unit from % to vh (I was trying to make it with a max height of 0, so it was working weird.) I've updated the fiddle with the changes. EDIT: Yes, #navbar needed to be `position:absolute` so that it would be at the top, no margins.

Comment: @PorygonZRocks *"#navbar needed to be position:absolute so that it would be at the top, no margins."* you know the margins will go away if you add `body { margin: 0; }` right?

Comment: Oops, I forgot about that. Well, two working solutions  now!

Comment: @PorygonZRocks hah awesome. Yeah you shouldn't use position:absolute unless needed. It removes that element from the normal flow of the page so other elements won't flow around it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the drop down relative to the parent if its going to be in absolute position.
Set the parent position to relative, and then the dropdown will be positioned inside or within the parent tag.
Like Example:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div class="dropdown" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes it blank. [fiddle with your changes](https://jsfiddle.net/PorygonZRocks/mdfqs4xq/4/)